# change MSChart Background for printing

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have put in code to change the MSCharting area colour when printing.

```
chart.ChartAreas[o].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chart.Printing.PrintPreview();
```

My quesiton is, how can I handle the color to change back to its oringinal color, eitehr after user has selected Print, or Close form the printpreview dialog,, or if the click on the dialogs "X".

In fact if I use the PrintDialog instead, how could I set background back to normal once printing has been completed or canceled?

Answer (score 1):

little late but I hope it helps someone.

To MsChart print I'am using `PrintDocument` events. `BeginPrint` event for setting colors for printing, `PrintPage` event for print itself and `EndPrint` event for setting colors back before print.

Sample code:

```
 public GraphFrm()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     //new PrintDocument object to reset default one
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
     //set up events
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDocument_PrintPage);
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.BeginPrint +=new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(PrintDocument_BeginPrint);
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.EndPrint += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(PrintDocument_EndPrint);
     //default print setting like margins and landscape
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 50;
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 50;
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 50;
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 50;
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
     chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;

     ...
  }

  public void Print()
  {
     //print method with show print dialog
     chart.Printing.Print(true);
  }

  void PrintDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
  {
     //set print color
     PrintChartColorSet();
  }

  void PrintDocument_EndPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
  {
     //restore colors
     PrintChartColorRestoreDefault();
  }

  void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
  {
     //print chart into rectangle defined by margins
     Rectangle chartPosition = new Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.X, e.MarginBounds.Y, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);

     chart.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, chartPosition);
  }

  Color BackColor, BorderlineColor, CaBackColor, CaBorderColor, AxColor, LeBackColor, LeForeColor;

  void PrintChartColorSet()
  {
     BackColor = chart.BackColor;
     chart.BackColor = Color.White;

     BorderlineColor = chart.BorderlineColor;
     chart.BorderlineColor = Color.White;

     CaBackColor = chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.White;

     CaBorderColor = chart.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;

     AxColor = chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].LineColor;

     foreach(Axis a in chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes)
     {
        a.LineColor = Color.Black;
        a.TitleForeColor = Color.Black;
        a.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        a.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Black;
        a.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        a.MinorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Black;
        a.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
     }

     LeBackColor = chart.Legends[0].BackColor;
     chart.Legends[0].BackColor = Color.White;

     LeForeColor = chart.Legends[0].ForeColor;
     chart.Legends[0].ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }

  void PrintChartColorRestoreDefault()
  {
     chart.BackColor = BackColor;
     chart.BorderlineColor = BorderlineColor;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = CaBackColor;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor = CaBorderColor;

     foreach(Axis a in chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes)
     {
        a.LineColor = AxColor;
        a.TitleForeColor = AxColor;
        a.MajorGrid.LineColor = AxColor;
        a.MajorTickMark.LineColor = AxColor;
        a.MinorGrid.LineColor = AxColor;
        a.MinorTickMark.LineColor = AxColor;
        a.LabelStyle.ForeColor = AxColor;
     }

     chart.Legends[0].BackColor = LeBackColor;
     chart.Legends[0].ForeColor = LeForeColor;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there is no easy way since PrintPreview doesnt provide any callbacks.

You can make a copy of the chart used solely for printing with the default chart area replaced by your custom area (with custom background).

Another way is to change the BG Color, print the chart to a in-memory image using PrintPaint, restore the BG Color and show a print dialog manually for the image you just rendered.

There are more ways like hooking the newly created window but they are getting more complex and more dirty.

Good luck